# relayjs returning strange values for connections via REQUIRED_CHILDREN after mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

With relay.js, for some reason when I do a mutation and get a return value with REQUIRED_CHILDREN in `getConfigs`, connections are being returned with a strange alias: `_tierItems2EmfF3`where it should be `tierItems`.

When I make the same mutation through GraphiQL, the connection is returned properly.

I am not sure if this is some kind of configuration issue, but I have no idea what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

That's intentional: the alias is actually there to encode the connection arguments. It's a relatively simple hash of things like `first: 5`. You shouldn't actually care what the aliased result is, though, since it's only used by the Relay internals to make sure that connection results are associated with the right containers (since you could have, for example, two containers fetching the same connection with different arguments).